# How can I go from First ViewController to Second ViewController, get values and go back to First

Tags: macos, swift3, segue, nsviewcontroller

I just spent couple of days for trying to figure this out for mac app, but not doing it successfully.

I have first ViewController and second ViewController.  Let's say, ViewControllerA(VC-A) and ViewControllerB(VC-B).  In Main.storyboard, they are connected by segue with identifier "PromptToUser".

VC-B gets triggered not by button, but if condition during the process.
It is triggered by:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "PromptToUser", sender: self)
```

in VC-A.

In VC-A, I put the followings so far:

`override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
}`

In VC-B, so far, I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Login: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Pass: NSSecureTextField!
```

VC-B also has a button which I want to make as a trigger to collect information entered by user for above variables and send it back to first view.

I found many similar topics on this in stackoverflow.  However, it seems most of them are for iOS, but not for mac app as I could not make UI... and other classes (delegates) and protocols they mentioned to be recognized for Swift 3 environment.  I have NSViewController, and NS... not UI...

What would be the best way to approach this for mac app with Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

You Can make a static variable in VC-A and just update the value of static variable from VC-B. Example

In VC-A

```
static var login = ""
static var password = ""
```

In VC-B

```
VC-A.login =  nameTextField.text
VC-A.password = passTextField.text
```

Write the code in SaveButton Action of VC-B, and you will get the update value in VC-A.
If You are not using any Save Button in VC-B, then You can write code in viewWillDisappear Method of VC-B

```
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
          firstVC_A.login =  nameTextField.text
          firstVC_A.password = passTextField.text

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I just tried it by creating static variable in VC-A as you mentioned:  static var login = "", static var password = "".  In VC-B, created:  IBAction func submit (_ sender: Any) { VC-A.login = Login.stringValue, VC-A.password.stringvalue}, but it does not taking anything that I typed in these NSTextField.  It is always empty.  Also, .text is not recognized, so I had to do this with .stringValue.  This is also same part that I had issue when I referenced other post.  They all use .text, but that does not work for mac app, I guess.